# Documentation for writing GNOME Shell extensions

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

I've been asked to customise the layout of the GNOME 3 desktop. Apparently the way to do that is by writing an "extension".

I've managed to do some of the things I wanted to do, but I feel utterly *starved* of information. I cannot find any useful documentation *anywhere*. I've wasted entire *days* of my life frantically googling every imaginable search term in a desperate attempt to find useful information.

The GNOME website has *hundreds* of extensions for download. These are not trivial 3-liners; they're sophisticated pieces of code. It defies belief that anybody could write these without documentation explaining how to do it.

Please, can somebody tell me where the actual documentation is? So far, the best I've managed to do is take apart existing extensions trying to track down the magic command that does the specific bit I'm interested in. (Not an easy task!)

Command names, object paths, example programs, *anything* would be helpful!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I have recently dug into it myself. The documentation is usually sparse or outdated. Here are some sources which helped me to get started (and through development):

- [Basic Stuff](https://gjs.guide/extensions/)
- [Step-by-step tutorial (Gnome 3.4)](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial)
- [**Unofficial documentation for the JavaScript bindings of many libraries**](http://www.roojs.com/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/gjs/index.html)
- [**The sources of the gnome-shell's JavaScript bindings**](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/js)
- [Explanation of the St (Shell Toolkit) Ui-Toolkit components.](http://mathematicalcoffee.blogspot.de/2012/09/gnome-shell-javascript-source.html)
- [Some unofficial guidelines to get your extension on extensions.gnome.org](http://blog.mecheye.net/2012/02/requirements-and-tips-for-getting-your-gnome-shell-extension-approved/)

Since the documentation is nearly unavailable (or up to date), you'll need to do **a lot** of source-reading. I linked the gnome-shell sources above (the JavaScript part) which is a good start when diving into parts that are not covered by the In-official documentation (which is the most complete thing you'll find).

What's also particular helpful is checking [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org) for extensions which do similar things to what you want to create, and look at their sources (most of them are open-source on GitHub or Bitbucket. You can also install them and find the sources under `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`).

When searching for something to use or more documentation on a particular function, you can also consult manuals for bindings in different languages (thought the parameters and return-values might not match).

---

Last but not least, here is some **debugging advice**:

LookingGlass is not particularly helpful. It only shows one line of an exception (the description) and only if they occur at startup time (when your extension is first started).

For full StackTraces and runtime-exceptions, consult the `~/.xsession-errors`-file. It might be very long and bloated. I use this [handy script](https://bitbucket.org/LukasKnuth/backslide/src/561b1dbe542a/session-error.sh) to read it:

```
# Grabs the last session-errors from the current X11 session.
# This includes full Stack-Trace of gnome-shell-extension errors.
# See https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial#lookingGlass
tail -n100 ~/.cache/gdm/session.log | less
```

> **Note** that since Gnome 3.6, if you are using `gdm` as display manager, the current session log is the file `~/.cache/gdm/session.log`.

On some newer distros using systemd, you can get the error logs with:

```
journalctl -f /usr/bin/gnome-session
```

For **debugging the prefs-part** of your extension, you can launch the preferences by using the `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`-tool from a terminal, to see any exception-output on the console (you can also call the tool like `gnome-shell-extension-prefs [uuid]`, to directly show your extensions preferences).

Since there is currently no real way of debugging with breakpoints (there is, but [it's tricky](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Debugging)), you can **log on the console** for quick checking, use the `print()`-function. You will see the output as mentioned above (either in the sessions-error file or on the terminal when starting `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`-tool).

---

Although it might be a little hard to get into it, the extension framework is quite powerful. Have **fun**!

---

I wrote a **Blog-Post with somewhat greater detail**, which can be found here: [Making Gnome-Shell Extensions](https://lknuth.dev/writings/making_gnome_shell_extensions/)

Comment: It is also possible the gnome-session logs may be found in ~/.cache/upstart/gnome-session-GNOME.log (for example, on Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 15):

An extensive list of references can be found on the [Gnome Developer - API Reference](http://developer.gnome.org/references) page.

I used the following for my extension, but your use may vary:

- **[GTK+ 3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/)**
  GTK+ is the primary library used to construct user interfaces in GNOME applications. It provides user interface controls and signal callbacks to control user interfaces.
- **[GDK 3](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/)**
  GDK is an intermediate layer which isolates GTK+ from the details of the windowing system.
- **[Clutter](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/)**
  Clutter is a GObject based library for creating fast, visually rich, graphical user interfaces.
- **[GObject Introspection](https://developer.gnome.org/gi/stable/)**
  GObject Introspection is striving to provide a middleware layer between (GObject based) C libraries and language bindings.
- **[Shell](https://developer.gnome.org/shell/stable/)**
  Shell Reference Manual
- **[St](https://developer.gnome.org/st/stable/)**
  St - *Shell Toolkit* - is the GNOME Shell's custom Clutter-based toolkit that defines useful actors. Some of these actors, such as `StBoxLayout` and `StBin` implement various layout options.
- **[Icon Theme Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/icon-theme-spec/)**
  This [freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/) specification describes a common way to store icon themes.

**NOTE:** These last two are very helpful in finding visual element parameters!

- **[PyGTK](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/)**
  PyGTK is GTK+ for Python. This reference contains a chapter for each Python PyGTK module (that corresponds to the underlying GTK+ library) containing the class descriptions.
- **[PyGObject](https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/)**
  PyGObject is a Python extension module that gives clean and consistent access to the entire GNOME software platform through the use of GObject Introspection. Specifically speaking, it is Python Bindings for GLib, GObject, GIO and GTK+.
  This reference contains a chapter for each PyGObject module containing the class descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is on:

https://gjs.guide/extensions/

For the documentation of libraries:

https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/

More details on https://gjs.guide/extensions/overview/architecture.html

The other stuff you might want to check are

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/main/js/ui/popupMenu.js

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/main/js/ui/dialog.js

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/main/js/ui/modalDialog.js

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/main/js/ui/panelMenu.js

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/tree/main/js

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter

You can browse under `js/` for more code to be reused.

You might also want to check https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

**Question:**

I could not find anything under https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/ except some CSS and Javascript documentation ?!?!

**Answer:**

You have to first enable the docs to use them. Here, you will be mainly looking for:

- clutter
- meta
- shell
- st

Create a file like:

```
echo '{"docs":"clutter9~9_api/clutterx118~8_api/gobject20~2.66p/meta9~9_api/shell01~0.1_api/st10~1.0_api","hideIntro":"1"}' > devdocs.json
```

Import this file to https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/settings

Now you will be able to visit:

[https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/shell01~0.1_api-global/](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/shell01%7E0.1_api-global/)

[https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/shell01~0.1_api/](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/shell01%7E0.1_api/)

[https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/meta9~9_api/](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/meta9%7E9_api/)

[https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10~1.0_api/](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10%7E1.0_api/)

[https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter9~9_api/](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter9%7E9_api/)

[https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter9~9_api-actor/](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter9%7E9_api-actor/)

**Warning:** The version on the `devdocs.json` file is hardcoded. It will be outdated in no time, so you might want to check the version. The point is - you can not access docs until you enable them.

**P.S.** I know, this is a mess. This is how they did it.